# Msgbox from formula result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, messagebox, vba

I am trying to add a message box if the above formulas return an error or if the cells in the selection are blank, but as of yet have not been able to complete. Any ideas?

```
 LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Range("z2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'Ship to'!$B:$C,2,0)"
 Range("z2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("z2:z" & LastRow)
 LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Thanks again for your help

Phill

Comment: What have you tried to do to accomplish this, and where have you run into problems?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [IsError method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278547.aspx) to check if a cell formula is returning an error:

```
For Each cell in Range("z2:z" & LastRow)

   If IsError(cell) then
      ' do what you need to do
   End If

Next cell
```